# Sort array twice, save first sort and append second sort

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have `var array: [Double] =  [0.0, 1.000002, 0.0, 0.0]`.

I want to sort my array. First time me need sort by my **priority**, like this:

`secondElement: 1.000002`

`firstElement: 0.0`

`thirdElement: 0.0`

`fourthElement: 0.0`

And later me need second sort by **arc4random**, but need save first sort (var2 on **top of all**. Other elements sort by **arc4random**). I want to see my array like this:

`secondElement: 1.000002`

`thirdElement: 0.0`

`firstElement: 0.0`

`fourthElement: 0.0`

or

`secondElement: 1.000002`

`thirdElement: 0.0`

`fourthElement: 0.0`

`firstElement: 0.0`

Comment: "var array: [String: Double]" That's a Dictionary, and that's not sorted by definition.

Comment: yes, my mistake, fixed the issue

Comment: If we can suppose that you have an array and not a dict, you can sort (did you try it?), once done, you can get the first item and do a subarray with the rest, randomize it, and then reconstruct the array by adding first the previous first one.

Comment: i sorted only first time, second time i don't know how to do it

Comment: For better understanding it would be easier to have `var array: [Double] =  [0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]`, that way you don't have to explain "thirdElement" or such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var array: [Double] =  [0.0, 1.000002, 0.0, 0.0]
let sorted: [Double] = array.sorted(by: >)
let sortAndRandomize: [Double] = sorted.prefix(1) + sorted.dropFirst().shuffled()
```

---

If you'd like to mutate the original array, then:

```
var array: [Double] =  [0.0, 1.000002, 0.0, 0.0]
array.sort(by: >)
array = array.prefix(1) + array.dropFirst().shuffled()
```

Comment: if I have such an array? `var array: [Double] =  [0.0, 1.000002, 1.000003, 0.0]`
how do I do that?

Comment: @ДмитрийДеникаев what is the result you want? If you use the same code above then the result would be `[1.000003, 0.0, 0.0, 1.000002]` or `[1.000003, 0.0, 1.000002, 0.0]` or `[1.000003, 1.000002, 0.0, 0.0]`

Comment: but I want to see result [1.000003, 1,000002, 0.0, 0.0]

Comment: @ДмитрийДеникаев `array.sorted(by: >)` or `array.sort(by: >)` will do

Comment: but this code ‘array.dropFirst.shuffled()’ will remove first element and 1.000002 will shuffled with third and fourth elements. In final result I will see [1.000003, 0.0, 1.000002, 0.0], am I wrong?

Comment: @ДмитрийДеникаев That line won't be needed